# RVIZ not showing Robot, Global Status = No tj data. Actual Error: Frame [base_footprint] does not exist

Tags: ros2

I am using Linorobot2 to get an AMR robot built. (https://github.com/linorobot/linorobot2)

I am getting stuck at the "Visualize the newly created URDF" portion. I am able to edit my description file and colcon build, but then when I launch via robot computer I get stuck with below line (no actual error but just waits there forever). Command "ros2 topic list" shows what I would expect as well.

Further steps like launching robot and controlling via keyboard works, but URDF and SLAM all get stuck waiting for this robot_description topic.

"joint_state_publisher: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic"

EDIT: Another user ran this code, and the code above is correct. However, they do get robot visualized in RVIZ. When I run my launch file for description.rviz the RViz software comes up but its just blank axes. So thinking it is a RVIZ mesh issue or perhaps a directory issue with the launch file, but other user installed same way and had no issue.

Error showing in RVIZ is: "Global Status" "No tf data. Actual Error: Frame [base_footprint] does not exist.

Any ideas whats causing this hangup? I have seen previous posts of this kind say it is related to directory setup and the launch file looking in the wrong place but I doubled checked it looks good to me.

Edit2: Adding picture of the URDF file I edited, I only changes the numbers slightly from default file

[image]

Comment: What does your launch file look like? Also what does the output of `ros2 topic info --verbose <description_topic>` look like?

Comment: Result of that code is "Unknown topic 'linorobot2_description". Launch file is at this link: https://github.com/linorobot/linorobot2/blob/master/linorobot2_description/launch/description.launch.py

Comment: Based on your edit, and the fact you're changing the URDF file means you have a broken transform. Some joint is not corrected right in your URDF, but it's impossible to say what without seeing the file or output of `rqt_tf_tree`

Comment: I just added picture of the URDF file, I only edits some numbers slightly so hoping that wouldnt break anything. For rqt_tf_tree, where should I run this to output what you want to see?

Comment: Also, I opened config within RViz, within the directory where I edited the files its blank, but if I go to that folder in my command line I see files as expected.